# I'm confused about URL sanitization in meta boxes

Tags: metabox, urls, sanitization

I'm making a meta box for a custom post and this meta box will contain a href value. I don't need any validation as this is a valid href value but I would like to do this in a way that's secure.

I have built my meta box with [this tutorial](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/).

In the part where to sanitize the input I have used `esc_url_raw()` and it seems to work just fine, but the Codex says on `esc_url_raw()`:

> This function is not safe to use for displaying the URL, use
>   `esc_url()` instead

So should I use `esc_url()` or is there something [else](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) that I should be using and if so, why should I not use `esc_url_raw()` in this case?

My Code:

```
/* Get the posted data and sanitize it */
$new_meta_value = ( isset( $_POST['mod-modbox-link'] ) ? esc_url_raw( $_POST['mod-modbox-link'] ) : '' );
```

I get the URLs to pages with this:

```
$my_link = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mod_modbox_link', true );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choice between `esc_url` and `esc_url_raw` depends on the use you have to do with the url.

If you have to use the url to **display** inside html use `esc_url`, E.g.:

```
$my_link = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mod_modbox_link', true );
echo '<a href="' . esc_url($my_link) . '">Open link</a>'
```

`esc_url_raw` should be used for any other use, where the url should be treated as a valid url, e.g. redirect:

```
$my_link = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mod_modbox_link', true );
wp_redirect( esc_url_raw($my_link) );
```

or [HTTP API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) functions:

```
$my_link = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mod_modbox_link', true );
$response = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw($my_link) );
```

This is because `esc_url` converts special htmlentities in their encoded versions, `esc_url_raw` doesn't.
E.g. if your url is something like `http://example.com/index.php?foo=bar&bar=baz` that is a full valid url, when you use `esc_url` the `&` is converted in `&#038` not when you use `esc_url_raw`.

Codex say to use `esc_url_raw` also to save url in db, and in your case the post meta is saved in database, so you should use `esc_url_raw` when you set the meta:

```
$link = isset($_POST['meta']) ? esc_url_raw($_POST['meta']) : '';
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mod_modbox_link', $link );
```

Then when you retrieve it, use `esc_url_raw` or `esc_url` according to your needs: if you have to print in the html use `esc_url` otherwise use `esc_url_raw`.